Removing specific parts/data from a point cloud
If i have a point cloud, for example of a metal object that has a few extrusions/unwanted parts like in the image, are there any clustering methods to remove such extrusions? I've tried using Euclidean Cluster Extraction from PCL, but as expected it cant isolate them very well. So i was wondering if there are other methods that i could use. If clustering is not the right method at all, what else can i look into?
Metal object

nevermind, region growing segmentation with the right parameters works pretty well
